# Why does array's object property correctly access to the value?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the following object:

```
var obj = {
   "Name of something": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
   }
};
```

I wonder why the following code works properly?

```
var title = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(obj[title])  // {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

How does `title` access to `Name of something` object's property of `obj`? `title` is array is it?

Comment: No. `person["name"]` is just another way of writing `person.name` in Javascript. Using the `obj.property` notation is just somewhat limiting as of which characters can be used for the name of `property` (you can't use spaces, operators etc. using `.`-notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object has only one key, so `Object.keys` returns the array

```
["Name of something"]
```

If you convert that array to a string, which is what happens when you pass it as a key

```
["Name of something"].toString()
```

You get

```
"Name of something"
```

Which is the key for your object, so end up with

```
obj["Name of something"] // returns {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```